# Migrate a question from StackOverflow to mathematica.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202531/minimizing-nexpectation-for-a-custom-distribution-in-mathematica/32261073#32261073), which I posted at StackOverflow in ***February 2012*** before the Mathematica site launched (or at least before I knew about its existence).

It's gotten:

- a slew of up votes from the StackOverflow community (231 and counting),
- a bunch of comments,
- someone even put a bounty on it, but

it never got a single answer UNTIL YESTERDAY.

I still need to study it, but on first look it looks like a good answer.

So, my question -- Given that it is really a Mathematica question, would it make sense to get it moved to ***mathematica.stackexchange.com*** so more of the Mathematica community would see/benefit from it?

If yes, how does one go about it?

I also want to keep mindful of all the attention the question got over at StackOverflow.

Thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, mods no longer have the ability to migrate sufficiently old questions. But, I'll try asking around…

Comment: @J.M.  I know its old, but it has been pretty active with a bunch of recent comments and now (miraculously) an answer.

Comment: It seems very funny to me that it's received so much attention and admiration, but without any productive responses until recently. I wonder what draws SO users who clearly don't know much/anything about *Mathematica* to certain questions like this. Anyway, I agree it would be better migrated here. The answerer [has an account](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29298/azt) on this site already. I am not sure if migrating will mess up the bounty award, so maybe it is better to wait until that is done, if it will be a problem.

Comment: Update: I've asked, but nobody seems able or willing to do the migration. :( If need be, you can repost your question here instead, and see if you can convince the answerer to also repost his answer here.

Comment: I did the answer on SO, since it was worth a Bounty of 150 and found it interesting. Sure, I'll repost it here, if you repost the question here. But it would be nice to not loose the Bounty on SO ;)

Comment: @azt -- I just posted the [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94295/minimizing-nexpectation-for-a-custom-distribution) our site.